# Java. Массив строк. Найти самое длинное слово

Tags: java, массивы

Java. Найти самое длинное общее слово двух заданных предложений.
Есть 2 предложения. Нужно найти 1 самое длинное слово, которое присутствует в двух предложениях.

Comment: Вот так, в приказном порядке?

Comment: Если есть возможность и желание - можно помочь. Если нет, то и читать смысла нет.

Comment: Желание помогать у большинства людей, как правило, возникает в ответ на просьбу о помощи, а не на приказ выполнить. На будущее...

Answer (score 0):

Думаю задание носит образовательный характер, поэтому просить сделать его за Вас мне кажется неуместным. Могу только подсказать как можно решить задачу. [ССЫЛКА.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0)